# How to check if Image in ImageView Array is set to 'null'?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create a counter that increases if an Image contained in an ImageView array is set to null.  I have a Bullet class that calls the method below

Whenever I kill an enemy it sets the image to 'null'

```
 public void Collision(ImageView ene[], Rectangle b){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 * wave; i++) {

        if (ene[i].getBoundsInParent().intersects(b.getBoundsInParent())){
            ene[i].setVisible(false);
            ene[i].setImage(null);
            score();
            bulletGone();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that it prints out the first "Null count: " in the checkWave method, but never reaches the for loop.  Am I comparing to null incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this `checkWave(ImageView e[])`
now check your `Collision` method pal, who do you set to null? go back to your `checkWave(ImageView e[])` method, who you check for null?

hope you find your solution.

one tip: `int counter = 10 * wave;//its final`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 * wave; i++) {//save yourself some keys
or (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
```

EDIT

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    if (e[i].getImage() == null){ //now your loop will do
        nullCount++;
        System.out.println("Null count: " + nullCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you for the 'final' tip, forgot to change that.  As for the null point, I call the same ImageView array for both methods, which is why I'm confused as to why its not entering the for loop.  For the collision method I call it in my Bullet class as Collision(badGuys, bullet) then call the checkWave in my score method as checkWave(badGuys).  Is there a way I can check if everything in the array is null without iterating through each one?

Comment: sir @CNiche dont confuse yourself if you look in `Collision(ImageView ene[], Rectangle b){` you are setting the `Image` field in the `ImageView` to `null` in your `checkWave(ImageView e[])` you are checking if they are null, that is items in the array are not pointing to any object and they are,  do you get it, also are you asking for a different approach?

Comment: OHHH I get it, I just thought the .setImage(null) wouldve also reference the ImageView.  Is there a way I can point the null value to my ImageView object? I mean I was hoping I could get this working, but I never say no to other ideas, a different approach may also help me understand more!